# How to make a button trigger an event (Timer)?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a fire evacuation project and would like to trigger an event after clicking a button. Basically I want to begin the fire evacuation process manually using the button feature but would like to trigger a timer for about 60 seconds to give the pedestrians time to evacuate using the event feature.

I have tried to make pedestrians stop the evacuation process by manually clicking another button but would like to use an event trigger timer instead as this will be a better way to conduct my simulation. I cannot seem to trigger an event once the button is clicked. I've tried changing the trigger type but not sure where to go from there. Is there any code that is required or another step that is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Dynamic Event`](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/statecharts/Dynamic%20Event.html?cp=0_10_0_4) for this.

- Set it up by pulling it from the AnyLogic Agent Library to the Workspace and give it a name (here: *MyDynamicEvent*).
- Add the code you want to have executed when the timer runs off in the *Action* field
- Set one (or several) timed instance for this event by using the code `create_MyDynamicEvent(60,SECOND);`. Note: The syntax of this statement is always `create_` followed by the actual name you gave your DynamicEvent type.

[image: Dynamic Event Definition]

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 3):

Even though a dynamic event is fine in your application, you can also use a user control event:
[image: user controlled event]

And then in your button you can use the following code:

```
event.restart(60,SECOND); //you can choose any timeout here
```

or

```
event.restart(); // this will use the configuration, which in this case I set up to 60 seconds
```

The difference between a dynamic event and a user controlled event is that if you click the button again:

1. With the dynamic event, you will generate another instance of the event, meaning that if you click the button at t=0 seconds, and t=30 seconds, you will generate 2 events at t=60 seconds and t=90 seconds
2. With the user control event, you will restart the same event. if you click the button at t=0 seconds, and t=30 seconds, you will generate a unique event at t=90 seconds.

So depending on which one you prefer... you can choose. I would prefer the user control in case you click the button 2 times... or if you regret clicking it so fast... I don't know

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Yes your help is very much appreciated. I will consider both these methods.

Comment: I preferred using your method because it also shows me the time countdown before the evacuation process stops so thank you very much.